# Animate div from height: 0px to auto failing on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, velocity.js

I'm trying to animate a block element from 0px to auto. However, on first click it just instantly shows at its auto height. After the first click, it animates to visible and invisible smoothly just fine.

CSS:

```
.item .comments {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f7f8fb;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-comment', function(){

    var comments = $(this).closest('.item').find('.comments');

    if (!comments.is(':visible')) {
      comments.show().velocity({
          height: comments.get(0).scrollHeight
      }, 250, function(){
          $(this).height('auto');
      }, 'ease');
    } else {
      comments.velocity({
        height: 0
      }, 250, function(){
        $(this).hide();
      }, 'ease');
    }

});
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but height() takes a pixel value so auto may not work. Try using css() -- http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: I may be wrong cause the doc says -- When calling .height(value), the value can be either a string (number and unit) or a number. If only a number is provided for the value, jQuery assumes a pixel unit. If a string is provided, however, a valid CSS measurement must be provided for the height (such as 100px, 50%, or auto). Note that in modern browsers, the CSS height property does not include padding, border, or margin.

Comment: $(this).height('auto');  -- is the button you clicked == have you tried $(comments).height('auto');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `slideToggle()` like this:

```
$(this).closest('.item').find('.comments').slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've just forgotten to type

```
  height: 0;
```

in the CSS. This makes it set to auto in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I think in jQuery is not such a function you can toggle click so i made for you one, https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/zobbvm79/ I'm new to JS,and i think the animation you can give it to css,and `addClass` and `removeClass` is the main point of this action